# RSPEC - Test says object is nil, but works fine in practice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

I can't figure out why this object keeps coming up as nil.

Here is the error:

```
  1) Item Calculate with just Total
     Failure/Error: subject.calculate_tax(tax, sub_category)
     TypeError:
       nil can't be coerced into Fixnum
     # ./app/models/item.rb:111:in `+'
     # ./app/models/item.rb:111:in `calculate_tax'
     # ./spec/models/item_spec.rb:26:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Here is the line it applies to - it thinks "self.tax_rate" is nill (second last argument)

```
self.tax_amount     = ((self.total - self.deduction) - ((self.total - self.deduction) / (1 + self.tax_rate))) * self.tax_adjustment
```

Here is my Test

```
describe Item do
  subject {Item.new(:report_id => 26 ,  :name => 'Gas' ,:tax_rate => 0.13, :tax_id => 1 ,  :category_id => 15 ,  :sub_category_id => 31 ,  :job_id => 1 , :total => 20 )}

  let(:tax) {Tax.where(id: subject.tax_id).first}
  let(:sub_category) {SubCategory.where(id: subject.sub_category_id).first}


  it 'Calculate with just Total' do

    subject.name.should be == 'Gas'
    tax = Tax.find_by_id(subject.tax_id)

    subject.sub_category_id.should be == 31
    subject.set_nil_values
    sub_category.should_receive(:taxable).exactly(3).times.and_return(sub_category.taxable)
    tax.should_receive(:rate).exactly(4).times.and_return(tax.rate)
    sub_category.should_receive(:tax_adjustment).and_return(sub_category.tax_adjustment)
    subject.calculate_tax(tax, sub_category)
    subject.should_receive(:tax_rate).exactly(2).times.and_return(tax.rate)
    subject.calculate_cost
    subject.cost.should be_within(0.01).of(17.70)
    subject.tax_amount.should be_within(0.01).of(2.30)
    subject.save
  end
```

Comment: What's your purpose in stubbing `tax.rate` given that you just want to return `tax.rate`?

Comment: Have you inspected the value of `tax.rate`?

Comment: How do I inspect elements in Rspec?

Comment: tax.rate has a value of .13 in practice, but comming up as nil only in testing.

Comment: Just print out (e.g. `puts`) the values in RSpec that you're intereste d in. For example. if `tax.rate` is nil immediately after doing the `find_by_id`, then you've got a problem with the `Tax` entry in your test database with `id` of 1.

Comment: How are you populating your test database such that you expect to lookup existing `Tax` entries?

Comment: LOL I -just- realized this.  This is my first test after watching code school.  I switched the test database to the development one and it works now.  How am I supposed fill the test database.  If you make the answer, I'll mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `taxes` table in your test database appears not to have an entry with `id` equal to 1 whose `tax.rate` is not `nil`